# Cycles - Baking Diffuse result is always black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I already try for hours to bake a diffuse map from multiple textures, but the result is always black.

This is my material:

[image: textured object]

I want to bake it, I already managed it earlier without any problems to bake the diffuse texture, but now suddenly the only result I get is black.

Here is my node setup for the material which I need to bake. I try to save the result in the node at the top left.
[image: cycles nodes]
**NOTE:** I know the Principled BSDF shader settings make no sense, I was just playing around to see if this makes a difference in the bake...

How I tried it:

1. Selected the object
2. Created a new uv-image
3. Create Texture node in my material and set the uv-image as source
4. Select that node (yellow border)
5. Bake diffuse

Result:

[image: bake result]

There are many lamps in the scene:

[image: lamps in 3D view]

[image]

Comment: Apparently, Baking Diffuse only works, if you're using a *Diffuse BSDF*, not only  a *Principled BSDF*.

Comment: @Leander, thats incorrect, as said I managed to bake the diffuse map without problems before (with the same material), and then I must have changed something and now it won't work anymore. Maybe because I switched to Blender Renderer and then back again?

Comment: I had a same problem, then I opened a new file append the object to that seen and did the same baking and ... no problem it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. After setting `Subsurface` to `0` in the *Principled BSDF* Shader, it works. I can't explain it though.

Comment: Principled BSDF's always worked for me but I am having same issue. I accidentally changed color of the subsurface. I undid that and changed the diffuse color instead. But when I bake all the materials to the object, that is the only one that is black in the resulting image. No idea what I am forgetting because I am comparing that material with the others and nothing looks awry.

Comment: @hatinacat2000 are you full metallic ? turn it to zeo before baking.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the reason of black image is the metallic value of principled BSDF shader. To bake "selected to active"  you need to ensure the metalness value of the selected object is is set to 0.