# How to bake node without freezing blender UI?

Tags: python, baking

I want to bake the node without freezing the UI similar to default blender bake.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator, Panel


class XX_OT_node_bake(Operator):
    bl_label = 'Bake'
    bl_idname = 'xx.node_bake'
    bl_options = {'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.area.type == 'NODE_EDITOR' and context.material and context.active_node and context.active_object and context.selected_nodes


    def execute(self, context):
        self.node_tree = context.material.node_tree

        for node in list(context.selected_nodes):
            if node.type in {'TEX_IMAGE', 'REROUTE', 'FRAME', 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL', 'SCRIPT', 'GROUP_INPUT', 'GROUP_OUTPUT', 'OUTPUT_AOV', 'OUTPUT_LIGHT'}:
                continue

            # nodes
            material_output = self.node_tree.nodes.get('XX_MATERIAL_OUTPUT')
            if not material_output:
                material_output = self.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')
                material_output.name = 'XX_MATERIAL_OUTPUT'
            material_output.target = 'CYCLES'
            material_output.location = node.location

            # links
            self.node_tree.links.new(output=node.outputs[0], input=material_output.inputs['Surface'])

            # image
            image = bpy.data.images.get(f'{node.name}_BAKED')
            if not image:
                image = bpy.data.images.new(name=f'{node.name}_BAKED', width=2048, height=2048, is_data=False, alpha=False, tiled=False, float_buffer=True)

            # image textrue node
            image_node = self.node_tree.nodes.get(f'{node.name}_BAKED')
            if not image_node:
                image_node = self.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
                image_node.name = f'{node.name}_BAKED'
            image_node.image = image
            image_node.location = (node.location.x, node.location.y + 30)
            image_node.width = node.width
            image_node.hide = True
            image_node.select = True
            self.node_tree.nodes.active = image_node


            override = context.copy()
            override['selected_objects'] = [context.object]
            # bake the node
            bpy.ops.object.bake(override,
                type = 'EMIT',
                margin = 8,
                use_clear = True,
            )

            # remove nodes
            self.node_tree.nodes.remove(material_output)

            node.select = True
            self.node_tree.nodes.active = node

        return {'FINISHED'}
    

class XX_PT_node_bake(Panel):
    bl_label = 'Node Bake'
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Bake'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.scale_y = 1.2
        layout.scale_x = 1.2

        col = layout.column()
        col.scale_y = 1.4
        col.operator('xx.node_bake')


classes = (
    XX_OT_node_bake,
    XX_PT_node_bake,
)


register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Use an *Emission* node instead of the *Principled BSDF* node if you want to bake a metallic map with bake type *Emit*. I've just double-checked and the *Principled BSDF* node does not work with bake type *Emit*. Related questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/95328/107598 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251964/107598

Comment: I am not baking a metallic map, I want to bake a particular node into image texture.

Comment: I haven't run your script but it looks like you bake the *Emit* bake type (bpy.ops.object.bake(override, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT', type = 'EMIT', ...) and in your first screenshot the *Principled BSDF*'s *Metallic* slot is connected to a *ColorRamp* node. So the input is not 0 and this doesn't work with the *Emit* bake type.

Comment: I want the bake operator to behave similar to default bake operator

Comment: When I remove the `INVOKE_DEFAULT` it freezes the blender UI

Comment: Please do not completely change your questions after they've been asked and answered

Comment: @Karan please don't deface you posts by altering your questions into something completely different after they've been answered. Any answers already posted no longer make sense. If you have a different question make a new post

Answer (score -1):

You need to instead bake with `type = 'Combined'`, not `'Emit'`

(this answer was given before the question changed)