# how to bake shaders / texture into pngs for export

Tags: export, texture-baking, baking

[image]so when I try and bake my shader to turn it into a texture it will either not work at all or it will turn black, my UV map is fine, I'm using only color (for bake type) and I have everything connected into the principle. I have tried a dozen of videos to try and help me bake a shader but it doesn't work, and I would greatly appreciate any help.
If it helps for context I am trying to bake textures so I can upload them into substance painter so I can export them into unity with the pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific? What specifically have you tried from dozen of videos and how did that not work for you? By the way, you don't bake the shader itself. You bake properties of the shader, lighting or geometry. Each property you bake will require a separate image map. Those could be color, bump, ambient occlusion, roughness, normals, glossiness, displacement, emission and so on. You cannot "bake a shader into a texture"(..usually. Unless it's a shadeless shader).

Comment: I tried to follow the videos step by step , and I dont know why they didnt work, that what im trying to figure out. I have a voronoi connected to a color ramp and then to a mix, thats also connected with a voronoi to a color ramp, and then after the mix its another mix (I disconnected the bottom one) then connected to a principle BSDF into a material output, and I then have a image texture im trying to bake to.

Comment: What were the steps you followed when it did not work?

Comment: Hello maybe share your file so that we can test, also show a screenshot of your material?

Comment: how do I post a screenshot and a link to the file here?

Comment: To post a screenshot, you need to edit your original question, to share a file use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions and copy paste the link it will generate)

Comment: just added them, thank you moonboots

Answer (score 1):

You are baking Diffuse, but you have Metallic=1. Metals always have black diffuse (because [any light that goes inside them is absorbed](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/1514)). See [this similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95328/cycles-baking-diffuse-result-is-always-black).

If you want to bake a texture that you can use for Base Color, the easiest way is to connect the socket going to Base Color directly to the Material Output and then bake Emit.

[image]